# Kalman Filter : some doubts

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, tracking, kalman-filter

I have several questions:

1. In the [example](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=cvkalman#cvKalmanCorrect) given in openCV document:

   /* generate measurement */
   cvMatMulAdd( kalman->measurement_matrix, state, measurement, measurement );

Is this correct?
In the tutorial: [An Introduction to the Kalman Filter](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.6578&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Welch and Bishop
in Equation 1.2 it says measurement = H*state + measurement noise

Doesn't seems both are same.

1. I was trying to implement [bouncing ball tracking](http://www.marcad.com/cs584/Tracking.html) for a single ball.
   I tried the following: (Please point out if I am doing it incorrectly.)

For the measurement I am measuring two things: a) x b) y of the centroid of the ball.

I am just mentioning lines which are different from the example given in opencv documentation.

```
CvKalman* kalman = cvCreateKalman( 5, 2, 0 );
const float A[] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1};

CvMat* state = cvCreateMat( 5, 1, CV_32FC1 );
CvMat* measurement = cvCreateMat( 2, 1, CV_32FC1 );

//initialize the state of kalman filter
            state->data.fl[0] = mean_c;
            state->data.fl[1] = mean_r;
            state->data.fl[2] = mean_c - prev_mean_c;
            state->data.fl[3] = mean_r - prev_mean_r;
            state->data.fl[4] = 9.81;
```

after initialization, this is what gives crash

**cvMatMulAdd( kalman->transition_matrix, state,
                    kalman->process_noise_cov, state );**

Comment: Check this link to a thread where Kalman explanations are discused:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478881/kalman-filtering-for-programmers

Answer (score 4):

1. In this line they just use variable measurement to store noise. See previous line:

   cvRandArr( &rng, measurement, CV_RAND_NORMAL,    cvRealScalar(0),cvRealScalar(sqrt(kalman->measurement_noise_cov->data.fl[0])) );
2. You should change dimension of `H` matrix as well. It must be 5 by 2 to make it possible to calculate `H*state + measurement noise`. You get an error probably in line

   memcpy( cvkalman->measurement_matrix->data.fl, H, sizeof(H));

because in initial example `cvkalman->measurement_matrix` and `H` are allocated as 4 by 4 matrices and you decreased dimension of `cvkalman->measurement_matrix` only to 5 by 2 (4*4 is more than 5*2)

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. They should have named the variable measurement_noise. 
But I think in the example in openCV documentation, H is 2 by 2 matrix not 4 by 4.
This [example(url link)](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/SEP/0607/vision/Code/Onboard%20Visual%20System/kalman.cpp) helped me in understanding better.

Comment: if your state vector is of dimension `n` and dimension of measurement is `m` then measurement matrix is `n` by `m`